# Amazon Drop Down Menu "Shop By Department" Appears on specific page width

Tags: jquery, css

On amazon.com, the drop down menu for the items under "shop by department" appears (without mousing over) if the width of my screen is larger then about 1260px, and disappears if I make the window smaller.

How do they accomplish this?

I have my own JS navigation (see the "dropdown" link on this demo page: http://html5up.net/strongly-typed) that I would like to appear and disappear based on the width of the page being viewed (in addition to it's existing mouse-over functionality).

Thanks!